# How to type "<" and ">" (greater and smaller than) in a chinese keyboard configured as a spanish one

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

I'm using a Chinese keyboard in a Windows 10 PC configured in Spanish. For the most part, everything works fine: in Chinese keybords, the key right next to <kbd>L</kbd> is <kbd>;</kbd> (semicolon), but in Spanish keyboards it's <kbd>ñ</kbd>. No problem, I just type <kbd>;</kbd> and I get <kbd>ñ</kbd>.

However, there are two characters that I can't get no matter how hard I try, "bigger than" and "smaller than" ( <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd>). In Spanish keyboards they have their own dedicated keys, but I don't have them here, and if I try with the marked keys (the ones next to <kbd>M</kbd>), I get <kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd>.</kbd> (which is what they are supposed to be in the Spanish layout).

How can I get these signs?

Comment: Have you tried pressing `Shift` and those keys?

Comment: Yep. SHIFT + those keys also have functions in spanish: they are ";" and ":" (semicolon and colon)

Comment: Hmm...if your chinese keyboard physically doesnt have that key, then (if on Windows) holding Windows key + `r` (Run box) and typing `osk` and pressing Enter (On Screen Keyboard) you can manually press it there. Also try out random keys on that screen to see if that key lights up to see if a key is actually configured for the <> key.

Comment: Is Chinese a JIS layout [or similar]? If so, your key *might* be far right on the numbers row, just left of Backspace; that's where JIS puts the key that on ISO would be left of Z.

Comment: @Tetsujin: it's a bopomofo keyboard. I just tried the key you mention (the one right next to backspace): it's labeled as "\", but I hit it and I get "ç".

Comment: eek - we're now well outside my comfort zone on international layouts, but… bopomofo is a kind of ANSI layout, like US but with different letters - which, if it's mapped similarly to ANSI vs ISO would put it left of 1. If it isn't, then I'm out of ideas, sorry :\